# Do something to line and next lines until a symbol is hit

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have data, that is set up as the following:

```
//Name_1   *   *
>a       xyzxyzyxyzyxzzxy
>b       xyxyxyzxyyxzyxyz
>c       xyzyxzyxyzyxyzxy
//Name_2  
>a       xyzxyzyxyzxzyxyx
>b       zxyzxyzxyyzxyxzx
>c       zxyzxyzxyxyzyzxy
//Name_3  *          *
>a       xyzxyzyxyzxzyxyz
>b       zxyzxyzxzyyzyxyx
>c       zxyzxyzxyxyzyzxy
...
```

The //-line refers to an ID for the following group of sequences until the next //-line is reached.
I have been working on writing a program, that reads the position of the asterix, and print the characters on the given position for the sequences.
To simplifiy things for myself, I have been working on a subset of my data, containing only one group of sequences, so e.g.:

```
//Name_1   *   *
>a       xyzxyzyxyzyxzzxy
>b       xyxyxyzxyyxzyxyz
>c       xyzyxzyxyzyxyzxy
```

My program does what I want on this subset.

```
import sys
import csv

datafile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

outfile = open(sys.argv[1]+"_FGT_Data", 'w')
csv_out = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')

csv_out.writerow(['Locus', 'Individual', 'Nucleotide', 'Position'])

with (datafile) as searchfile:
    var_line = [line for line in searchfile  if '*' in line]
    LocusID = [line[2:13].strip() for line in var_line]
    poslist = [i for line in var_line for i, x in enumerate(line) if x =='*']

datafile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')


with (datafile) as getsnps:
    lines = [line for line in getsnps.readlines() if line.startswith('>')]
    for pos in poslist:
        for line in lines:
            snp = line[pos]

            individual = line[0:7]
            indistr = individual.strip()
            csv_out.writerow((LocusID[0], indistr, line[pos], str(pos)))


datafile.close()
outfile.close()
```

However, now I am trying to modify it to work on the full dataset. I am having trouble finding a way to iterate over the data in the correct way.
I need to search through the file, and when a line containing '*' is reached, I need to do as in the above code for the sequences corresponding to the given line, and then continue to the next line containing an '*'. Do I need to split up my data with regards to the //-lines or what is the best approach?

I have uploaded a sample of my data to dropbox:
Data_Sample.txt contains several groups, and is the kind of data, I am trying to get the program to work on.
Data_One_Group.txt contains only one group, and is the data I have gotten the program to work on so far.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3j4i04s2rg6b63h/AADkWG3OcsutTiSsyTl8L2Vda?dl=0

--------EDIT---------

I am trying to implement the suggestion by @Julien Spronck below.
However, I am having trouble processing the produced block. How would I be able to search through the block line for line. E.g., why does the below not work as intended? It just prints the asterix' and not the line itself.

```
block =''
with open('onelocus.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if line.startswith('//'):
            #print line
            if block:
                for line in block:
                    if '*' in line:
                        print line

            block = line
        else:
            block += line
```

---------EDIT 2----------

I am getting closer. I understand that fact, that I need to split the string into line, to be able to search through them. The below works on one group, but when I try to itereate over several, it prints the information for the first group only. But does it for as many groups, as there are. I have tried clearing LocusID and poslist before next iteration, but this does not seem to be the solution.

```
block =''
with (datafile) as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if line.startswith('//'):
            if block:
                    var_line = [line for line in block.splitlines()  if '*' in line]  
                    LocusID = [line[2:13].strip() for line in var_line]
                    print LocusID
                    poslist = [i for line in var_line for i, x in enumerate(line) if x == '*'] 
                    print poslist



            block = line
        else:
            block += line
```

Comment: unrelated but opening a file and then using the file object in the context manager (`with`) defeats the purpose of using `with`

Comment: block is one string ... when you iterate over it, it goes through it character by character. Try this: `for line in block.splitlines(): ...`

Comment: see edit for a possible implementation of `do_something_with(block)`

Answer (score 2):

Can't you do something like:

```
block =''
with open(filename, 'r') as fil:
    for line in fil:
        if line.startswith('//'):
            if block:
                do_something_with(block)
            block = line
        else:
            block += line
if block:
    do_something_with(block)
```

In this code, I just append the lines of the file to a variable `block`. Once I find a line that starts with `//`, I process the previous block and reinitialize the block for the next iteration.

The last two lines will take care of processing the last block, which would not be processed otherwise.

`do_something_with(block)` could be something like this:

```
def do_something_with(block):

    lines = block.splitlines()

    j = 0
    first_line = lines[j]
    while first_line.strip() == '':
        j += 1
        first_line = lines[j]

    pos = []
    position = first_line.find('*')
    while position != -1:
        pos.append(position)
        position = first_line.find('*', position+1)

    for k, line in enumerate(lines):
        if k > j:
            for p in pos:
                print line[p], 
            print

## prints
## z y
## x z
## z y
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Julien Spronck. I am trying to implement your suggestion now. Just to make sure, is this the explanation of your answer: Open file. For line in the file. If the line stars with '\\'. If there is something in block. Do this to the block. (If there is nothing in block) block = line. If line does not start with '\\'. Append next line to block. ?

Comment: You're welcome. It's almost right ... except for the fact that `block = line` happens whether or not there is something in the block

Comment: Okay. I think what I am having trouble comprehending, is that it seems (for me) that we do something to the block, before all the lines are actually put into the block?

Comment: The first time you get to '\\...', `block = ''`, so we do not execute the line `do_something_with(block)`. Then you start building the block. Nex time, you get to '\\...', this marks the beginning of the new block but also the end of the previous one, so you process the previous one and then start anew. Makes sense?

Comment: The only thing that is missing is that, this code currently does not process the last block ... which then needs to be processed outside the loop (I'll make an edit about that)

Comment: Okay. Would I then searh line for line in block, to get the positions of asterix, print the characters on these positions etc.? I am thinking, that in principle, all of my above program, should be implemented in the "do_something_with(block)"-part of your suggestion?

Comment: indeed ... you mentioned that you had a piece of code that worked for a subset, that's what should be done in `do_something_with(block)` ... I did not look at that part but the idea is that you create a function that can process one block (finding the asterisks on the first line, ...), then you call your function for each block. I might have a look later but can't right now.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the program does not continue to next block.

Comment: @Hjalte I've just tried and it works for me ... There were two small problems though ... first I forgot to write `def ` before `do_something_with(block):` so that gives a syntax error, then I used the characters '\\' instead of '//'. Should now work. Let me know.

Comment: Okay, I can get your suggestion to work now. I do get a lot of blank spaces printed in the end, though. I don't know, why my version above does not iterate to the next block, though.

Comment: The printed blank spaces come from the blocks where there is no *. it's easy not to print them. about your version, i don't know it seems to print the correct * positions.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a way to make this work with the data you provided.
You should run it with 2 file locations, 1 should be your input.txt and 2 should be your output.csv

**explanation**

- first we create a dictionary with the locus as key and the sequences as values.
- We iterate over this dictionary and get the `*` locations in the locus and append these to a list `indexes`.
- We iterate over the values belonging to this key and extract the sequence
- per iteration we iterate over `indexes` so that we gather the snps.
- per iteration we append to our csv file.
- We empty the indexes list so we can go to the next key.

*Keep in mind*

- This method is highly dependant on the amount of spaces you have inside your input.txt.
- You should know that this will not be the fastest way to get it done. but it does get it done.

I hope this helped, if you have any questions, feel free to ask them, and if I have time, I will happily try to answer them.

---

**script**

```
import sys
import csv

sequences = []
dic = {}
indexes = []
datafile = sys.argv[1]
outfile = sys.argv[2]

with open(datafile,'r') as snp_file:
    lines = snp_file.readlines()
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        if lines[i].startswith("//"):
            dic[lines[i].rstrip()] = sequences
            del sequences[:]
        if lines[i].startswith(">"):
            sequences.append(lines[i].rstrip())

for key in dic:
    locus = key.split(" ")[0].replace("//","")
    for i, x in enumerate(key):
        if x == '*':
            indexes.append(i-11)

    for sequence in dic[key]:
        seq = sequence.split("    ")[1]
        seq_id = sequence.split("    ")[0].replace(">","")
        for z in indexes:
            position = z+1
            nucleotide = seq[z]

            with open(outfile,'a')as handle:
                csv_out = csv.writer(handle, delimiter=',')
                csv_out.writerow([locus,seq_id,position,nucleotide])
    del indexes[:]
```

---

**input.txt**

```
//Locus_1  *                    * 
>Safr01    AATCCGTTTTAAACCAGNTCYAT
>Safr02    TTAATCCGTTTTAAACCAGNTCY
//Locus_2      *             *    
>Safr01    AATCCGTTTTAAACCAGNTCYAT
>Safr02    TTAATCCGTTTTAAACCAGNTCY
```

---

**output.csv**

```
Locus_1,Safr01,1,A
Locus_1,Safr01,22,A
Locus_1,Safr02,1,T
Locus_1,Safr02,22,C
Locus_2,Safr01,5,C
Locus_2,Safr01,19,T
Locus_2,Safr02,5,T
Locus_2,Safr02,19,G
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up solving the problem:

`def do_something_with(block):`

```
lines = block.splitlines()
for line in lines:
    if '*' in line:
        hit = line
        LocusID = hit[2:13].strip()

        for i, x in enumerate(hit):
            if x=='*':
                poslist.append(i)
for pos in poslist:
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            individual = line[0:7].strip()
            snp = line[pos]
            print LocusID, individual, snp, pos,
            csv_out.writerow((LocusID, individual, snp, pos))   

with (datafile) as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if line.startswith('//'):
            if block:
                do_something_with(block)
                poslist = list()
            block = line
        else:
            block += line
if block:
    do_something_with(block)
```